# Floating button not changing positioned

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm having trouble in figuring out how to fix a floating button in the right place.

I've tried several things, but without success.

This is how It's currenlty looking.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LCjAu.png]

and the code

```
Widget myButtonTest(MediaQueryData mediaQuery){
  Widget child;
  if (widget.button == "video"){
  return Column(
        children: <Widget>[
        Center(
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 80.0),
          child: ClipPath(
            child: Container(
              child:AspectRatio(
                  aspectRatio: 1,
                  child: VideoPlayer(_controller),
                )
            ),
            clipper: BottomWaveClipper(),
          ))),
FloatingActionButton(
              onPressed: () {
                setState(() {
                  _controller.value.isPlaying
                      ? _controller.pause()
                      : _controller.play();
                });
              },
              child:Icon(
                Icons.play_arrow,
                color: Colors.red,
                size: 32.0,
              ),
              backgroundColor: Colors.white,
            ),
          
        ]
        );
        }
return Container(child: child);
}
```

And this is where I want the button.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping the floating action button with padding, and having the padding be:

```
padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0,0,0,100),
```

Also make sure the padding is on the Floating action button like this:

```
Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0,0,0,100),
      child: FloatingActionButton(
```

Comment: That's one thing I've tried out, but without success! But still, thank you!